# ARIMA: how to do prediction when the data is detrended by subtracting the moving average?

Tags: arima

Before fitting an ARIMA model, we found the trend of the ts is clearly nonlinear, so we remove the trend by subtracting the moving average (calculated by moving a sliding window over the ts and compute the mean of the numbers in the window) from the original data, after which the ts becomes stationary. But, how should I make a prediction in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Fit the ARMA model as your series is stationary now then you need to add earlier subtracted value ie. moving average to get forecasting of original data.